# Stargazer notes line wrap?

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

Is there a way to get `notes` in stargazer to wrap lines instead of running off the page?

```
stargazer(fit.1, notes="A very very long note that I would like to put below the table, but currently runs off the side of the page when I compile my document. How do I get this to wrap into paragraph form?")
```

Which produces:

```
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Notes:} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{*}$P $<$ .05} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{**}$P $<$ .01} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{***}$P $<$ .001} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{A very very long note that I would like to put below the table, but currently runs off the side of the page when I compile my document. How do I get this to wrap into paragraph form?} \\ 
\normalsize 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I couldn't find anything in the manual for adjusting this.

Comment: A quick fix is to use a `parbox` which would look something like this: `notes="\\parbox[t]{10cm}{Very long note goes here.}"` but may require manual changes if you adjust the models.

Answer (score 12):

The `notes` argument accepts a vector of character strings, and will put each on a new line. In your example, the following should work:

```
stargazer(linear.1, notes=c("A very very long note that I would like to put below the table,",
                     "but currently runs off the side of the page",
                     "when I compile my document.",
                     "How do I get this to wrap into paragraph form?"))
```

Comment: It would be great if a future version of stargazer would put every such element of the vector into its own parbox as per Bryan's comment above. Breaking lines manually seems inelegant at the very least.

Comment: @user1953965 I would also prefer a function to wrap lines automatically, breaking lines does not really produce a beautiful table

Answer (score 2):

I personally recommend a more Latex-y solution. Basically, create the table environment in your tex file, add caption etc. Then, paste or \input your stargazer output (with float = FALSE) in a minipage environment within the table environment, followed by your notes.

Ex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Your Caption}
    \begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth} 
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            999 & 888 & 777 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular} 
    \\
    \\
{ \footnotesize  Note: A very very long note that I would like to put below the table, but currently runs off the side of the page when I compile my document. How do I get this to wrap into paragraph form? \par} 
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

produces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCYy9.png

It's helpful to post a fully reproducible example as well. I know this is very old but the post still shows up in Google searches.