# Formatting notes in R's stargazer tables

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I am using `stargazer` package to produce (regression output) tables. Everything working miracles until I start editing the notes. **First**: line breaks are hard, but Bryan [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720264/stargazer-notes-line-wrap) a manual solution that is not elegant, but works. **Second** I need to make it start from the very left of the table.

Here is an example of the notes I am trying to produce from within `R`.
[image]

Produced by changing the original `LaTeX` code from:

```
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Logistic regression. Dependent variable: an indicator varible ... AND Some very long and interesting comment.} \\
```

To

```
   \multicolumn{5}{l} {\parbox[t]{11cm}{ \textit{Notes:} Logistic regression. Dependent variable: an indicator varible ... AND Some very long and interesting comment.}} \\
```

[image]

Editing by hand is time-consuming and error-prone. So I am looking for a way to solve this from `R`, where I am currently using the following:

```
stargazer([...],
          style = "qje", notes.append = FALSE, notes.align = "l",
          notes = "\\parbox[t]{7cm}{Logistic regression. Dependent variable: an indicator 
                   varible ... AND Some very long and interesting comment.}")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

stargazer returns its output invisibly as a character vector, specifically so you can post-process it.  Depending what you want to change, this may involve some regex. Or, as in this case, if you know what your notes line should look like, you can simply replace the wrong line with what you want.  Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10 + rnorm(100),
                 y = 1:10 + rnorm(100))
reg <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

star <- stargazer(reg,
          style = "qje", notes.append = FALSE, notes.align = "l",
          notes = "This will be replaced")


note.latex <- "\\multicolumn{5}{l} {\\parbox[t]{11cm}{ \\textit{Notes:} Logistic regression. Dependent variable: an indicator varible ... AND Some very long and interesting comment.}} \\\\"
star[grepl("Note",star)] <- note.latex
cat (star, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: how do you have the output to a tex file?

Comment: `write(star, 'file.tex')`

Comment: @dww: Did you choose the number of columns in \\multicolumns{.} arbitrarily?

Comment: @Eyayaw it was chosen to span all the columns  of the table above

Comment: Aha, I was looking at your example for which the number of columns 5 may not make sense. 5 makes sense in the question case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace 7cm with \textwidth, making your solution generic.

```
stargazer([...],
      style = "qje", notes.append = FALSE, notes.align = "l",
      notes = "\\parbox[t]{\\textwidth}{Logistic regression. Dependent variable: an indicator varible ... AND Some very long and interesting comment.}")
```

Comment: add `notes.label = ""` so that "Note:" will be suppressed & the note starts at the very left of the table.